# Verifying in Sequence

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to verify a set of method calls in sequence.

Here is a sample of what I would like to do. This test should fail, but it actually passes:

```
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        void Method(int i);
    }

    public class MyClass : IMyInterface
    {
        public void Method(int i)
        {
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();

        var listOfThings = new List<int> { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

        MethodUnderTest(mock.Object, listOfThings);

        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(1));
        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(2));
        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(3));
        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(4));
        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(5));
    }

    public void MethodUnderTest(IMyInterface myInterface, List<int> things)
    {
        foreach (var i in things)
        {
            myInterface.Method(i);
        }
    }
```

This should fail, as the `Verify` calls expect a different order of parameters.

I have tried `MockSequence` like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();

        var listOfThings = new List<int> { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

        var s = new MockSequence();

        mock.InSequence(s).Setup(m => m.Method(1));
        mock.InSequence(s).Setup(m => m.Method(2));
        mock.InSequence(s).Setup(m => m.Method(3));
        mock.InSequence(s).Setup(m => m.Method(4));
        mock.InSequence(s).Setup(m => m.Method(5));

        MethodUnderTest(mock.Object, listOfThings);

        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(1));
        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(2));
        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(3));
        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(4));
        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(5));
    }
```

But I guess I'm doing this wrong.

Using `MockBehaviour.Strict` doesn't seem to work either:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>(MockBehavior.Strict);

        var listOfThings = new List<int> { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

        mock.Setup(m => m.Method(1));
        mock.Setup(m => m.Method(2));
        mock.Setup(m => m.Method(3));
        mock.Setup(m => m.Method(4));
        mock.Setup(m => m.Method(5));

        MethodUnderTest(mock.Object, listOfThings);

        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(1));
        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(2));
        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(3));
        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(4));
        mock.Verify(m => m.Method(5));
    }
```

I can't use a `Setup` to configure the parameters passed into the mock call, as these values do not come from a mockable source.

Comment: What do you really want to test ? That `MethodUnderTest` calls `myInterface.Method` with `things` in the given order ?

Comment: @Spotted Correct.

Comment: As far as I understand (I don't use mocks) your test will fail anyway because of `listOfThings` declared as `5, 4, 3, 2, 1` and expecting beeing used as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

Comment: This test is supposed to fail, but it passes.

Comment: Ok. 1) I'm not sure I understand the purpose of writing a test that fails. 2) I don't see any value to test `MethodUnderTest` as there is no relevant logic that one may be interested to verify. 3) Verifying method calls with mocks (and even more a calls sequence) is considered a bad practice. **If you are willing**, I propose that you edit your code with the real meaning and that I help you to either refactor your test so that it provides a value or to conclude that your test is useless and remove it.

Comment: @rhughes did you find a way to achieve this? I'm trying the exact same thing 2 years later with the exact same result. And for thos of you who don't understand, it's quite easy : we want the calls to be made in a particular order. But if the test pass whatever the order, it's useless. That's why this failing test. Red, Green, Refactor.

Comment: @PatriceCote I marked the below answer as correct, so it is possible that it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating your mock with MockBehavior.Strict

```
var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

will allow you to verify the calls are in sequence.
The complete method would look like

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    //will fail
    var listOfThings = new List<int> { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    //will pass
    var listOfOtherThings = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    var s = new MockSequence();

    mock.InSequence(s).Setup(m => m.Method(1));
    mock.InSequence(s).Setup(m => m.Method(2));
    mock.InSequence(s).Setup(m => m.Method(3));
    mock.InSequence(s).Setup(m => m.Method(4));
    mock.InSequence(s).Setup(m => m.Method(5));

    MethodUnderTest(mock.Object, listOfThings);

    mock.Verify(m => m.Method(1));
    mock.Verify(m => m.Method(2));
    mock.Verify(m => m.Method(3));
    mock.Verify(m => m.Method(4));
    mock.Verify(m => m.Method(5));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I have updated my question.

Comment: you have to use the InSequence in combination with MockBehaviour.Strict. I've updated the answer with a full example